# is it anti-pattern to append .current after useRef in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've recently been debugging some old **React** code developed by my colleagues and noticed that they would declare *some* `useRef`'s inside their functional components like this:

```
const refName = useRef(...).current;
```

This isn't the first time I've seen `ref`'s declared like this in the **React** community, but it seems to be rare.

I can only assume that they've done this so that they only have to reference it by the variable name further down the line - as opposed to `variableName.current`.

So, this got me wondering: other than making the code a little bit cleaner, are there any clear downsides or benefits to declaring references this way?

Comment: The benefit is also that it's clear the reference will never be updated. It really just introduces a constant that is created once per component instance. (Lazy initialisation might be beneficial though)

Comment: @Bergi I'm curious what you mean by *lazy initialisation*. How would you implement that?

Comment: Using [`const [state] = useState(() => …)`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state) or [`const state = useMemo(() => …)`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) instead of `const state = useRef(…).current`, so that you don't just get the same value every time but also that `…` is evaluated only once. The memo is slightly better to understand but not 100% guaranteed to be called only once.